# Adding jQuery plugin as static resource

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am a noob to jQuery and VF in general...so bear with me :)

I am trying to replicate the example given in the below link for implementing a client level sort functionality for my     apex:pageblocktable

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25331/7755

In that example I believe the **table sorter plugin** is being referenced as a static resource via the following code.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/>
```

I am assuming that I have to create a static resource named "jquery.tablesorter.min.js".

Can someone tell me where to download this file containing this particular plugin ?

UPDATE :

http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Download

This page contains a zip file called "__jquery.tablesorter.zip".

This archive file inturn contains several folders & files.

[image]

Should I have to upload the entire archive file "_jquery.tablesorter.zip" for this plugin to work or can I upload only this particular file "jquery.tablesorter.min.js" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you take a whole ZIP. It is better to have all necessary files in one package.

- Rename `__jquery.tablesorter.zip` to `tablesorter.zip`
- Goto Salesforce Setup > Develop > Static resource
- Click on the New button
- Give Name, Description. Select your `tablesorter.zip` file as a source
- Save it
- On the visualforce page reference this static resource like this: 
  `<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/>`

This means that the file `jquery.tablesorter.min.js` should be loaded from the static resource with a name `tablesorter`

Comment: Thanks..One more question just for my knowledge ...if we upload the entire zip file as a static resource, the files under that archive will also be accessible right...?...because it is a zip file i am assuming that SF will be able to reach the decompress the archive and can read the specific file internally..am i right ?..let me know if i am not clear

Comment: @ZenSeeker Yes, you are right. Read this topic for more info: [What is a Static Resource?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_static_resources.htm&language=en_US)