# Sorting icon vf page

Tags: inline-visualforce

I have a vf page and I have implemented the sorting of column using the stackexchange post here [sorting columns in pageblocktable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25072/sorting-columns-in-pageblocktable).
The sorting is working fine. But I am not sure how to get the sorting icon( arrow mark down and up). Kindly help me on this.

Regards,
PSH

Comment: I am facing exactelly the same problem. Could you share what changes have you made in order to show the arrows? Thank you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to show the arrows because you are not referencing theme in the VF page. You need to upload complete tableSort zip file to static resource and reference theme to your vf page.

**

> Table sorter has theme blue with arrows images. I did some changes and
>   it is working fine.

** 
Take a look.

```
<apex:page controller="dataTableCon" id="thePage">
<head>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'themes/blue/style.css')}"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("table").tablesorter({debug: true});
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="rowspan" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Billing City</th>
            <th>Owner Name</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <apex:repeat value="{!Accounts}" var="a">
        <tr>

            <td><apex:outputText>{!a.name}</apex:outputText></td>
            <td><apex:outputText>{!a.BillingCity}</apex:outputText></td>
            <td><apex:outputText>{!a.Owner.Name}</apex:outputText></td>

        </tr>
         </apex:repeat> 
    </tbody>
</table>
    </body>






</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.Not getting the arrows.Added the sytlesheet statement as suggested by you.That didnt helped either.Any idea what i might be missing