# Trying to determine to best way to sort a table that contains combined data from two different sources

Tags: apex, visualforce, rss

I'm trying to determine to best way to sort a table that contains combined data from two different sources. One of the sources is an RSS feed that I'm currently parsing from xml into my custom object and the other is fed through parsed similarly, but from different source (API). These sources are parsed and combined into an object which is then displayed on the page in a table using apex repeat. I want to think the only real feasible way to do this is collate the data once it's parsed and then apply the sort in the controller by adding a button and attaching an event to it, but this doesn't seem like it "could" be the most efficient way, but this how I would do it in .net. Any suggestions or thoughts are appreciated. I was almost certain that there was a built in function for this. I was able to find https://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/ and [sorting columns in pageblocktable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25072/sorting-columns-in-pageblocktable), so I'm going to test this.

I'll give this girl a :bump: too, http://salesforcegirl.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-table-sorter-meets-salesforce.html.

Thank you btw.

Comment: Hi there. I've added the [tag:rss] tag for you, but could you please **[edit]** your question to provide additional details on whatever you may have tried so far, any research you've done, etc? It'd really help us out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooo, what I ended up doing was combining the objects into the one object and then using the JQuery tablesorter library and several different plugins to facilitate other sorting (date and special data). I guess you're wondering why I even asked this question, well again it had to relate to the feed and whether or not it would "lighter" to sort/filter the data before combining the sources. This question has really yet to be answered. Another thought is that I want the feeds "tagged" so people can gain info about the feed-item/link without having to click the link I'm providing. Thanks anyway. If I have time to load some analytics to help provide some substance to this question. Otherwise, good luck and have a nice day.